# Docker daemon.json logging config not effective

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, docker

I have a mongodb docker container (stock one downloaded from the docker repo). Its log size is unconstrained (/var/lib.docker/containers/'container_id'/'container_id'-json.log)

This recently caused a server to fill up so I discovered I can instruct the docker daemon to limit the max size of a container's log file as well as the number of log files it will keep after splitting. (Please forgive the naiveté. This is a tools environment so things get set up to serve immediate needs with an often painful lack of planning)

Stopping the container is not desirable (though it wouldn't bring about the end of the world) thus doing so is probably a suitable plan G.

Through experimentation I discovered that running a **different** instance of the same docker image and including `--log-opt max-size=1m --log-opt max-file=3` in the `docker run` command accomplishes what I want  nicely.

I'm given to understand that I can include this in the docker daemon.json file so that it will work globally for all containers. I tried adding the following to the file "/etc/docker/daemon.json"

```
{
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10m",
    "max-file": "3"
  }
}
```

Then I sent a -SIGHUP to the daemon. I **did** observe that the daemon's log spit out something about reloading the config and it mentioned the exact filepath at which I made the edit. (Note: This file did not exist previously. I created it and added the content.) This had no effect on the log output of the running Mongo container.

After reloading the daemon I also tried instantiating the **different** instance of the Mongo container again and it too didn't observe the logging directive that the daemon should have. I saw its log pass the 10m mark and keep going.

My questions are:

1. Should there be a way for updates to logging via the daemon to affect running containers?
2. If not, is there a way to tell the container to reload this information while still running? (I see `docker update` but this doesn't appear to be one of the config options that can be updated.
3. Is there something wrong with my config. I tested including a nonsensical directive to see if mistakes would fail silently and **they did not.** A directive not in the schema raised an error in the daemon's log. This indicates that the content I added (displayed above) is, at least, expected, though possibly incomplete or something. The commands seem to work in the run command but not in the config. Also, I initially tried including the "3" as a number and **that** raised an error too that disappeared when I stringified it.
4. I did see in the file "/var/lib.docker/containers/'container_id'/hostconfig.json" for the **different** instance of the Mongo container in which I included the directives in its run command that these settings were visible. Would it be effective/safe to manually edit this file for the production instance of the Mongo container to match the **different** proof of concept container's config?

Please see below some system details:

- Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd
- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

My main goal is to understand why the global config didn't seem to work and if there is a way to make this change to a running container without interrupting it.

Thank you, in advance, for your help!

Answer (score 6):

This setting will be the new default for newly created containers, not existing containers even if they are restarted. A newly created container will have a new container id. I stress this because many people (myself included) try to change the log settings on an existing container without first deleting that container (they've likely created a pet), and there is no supported way to do that in docker.

It is not necessary to completely stop the docker engine, you can simply run a reload command for this change to apply. However, some methods for running docker, like the desktop environments and Docker in Docker based installs, may require a restart of the engine when there is no easy reload option.

This setting will limit the json file to 3 separate 10 meg files, that's between 20-30 megs of logs depending on where in the file the third log happens to be. Once you fill the third file, the oldest log is deleted, taking you back to 20 megs, a rotation is performed in the other logs, and a new log file is started. However json has a lot of overhead, approximately 50% in my testing, which means you'll get roughly 10-15 megs of application output.

Note that this setting is just the default, and any container can override it. So if you see no effect, double check how the container is started to verify there are no log options being passed there.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the daemon.json for running containers did not work for me. Reloading the daemon and restarting the docker after editing the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` worked but only for the new containers.

```
docker-compose down
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
docker-compose up -d
```